# my app turned off when i click fragment button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm studying android studio by myself. but I have one problem.
I wrote a read db in my ThreeFragment.java.
but every time I click this fragment button, my add turn off.
I need your help.

this is my **ThreeFragment.java** code

```
package com.example.mybookapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment {
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_three);
        //2
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        //DB

        Context intent = null;
        DBHelper myDBHelper = new DBHelper(intent.getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase mydb = myDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = mydb.rawQuery("select title, rating, strftime('%Y-%m-%d', visited) from myRestaurant", null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
            textView.setTextSize(20);
            textView.setText("별점:" + cursor.getInt(1) + "|방문일:" + cursor.getString(2) + "|" + cursor.getString(0));
            linearLayout.addView(textView);

        }
        //db닫기
        mydb.close();
    }

    

    private void setContentView(int fragment_three) {
    }


}
```

Comment: Kindly add Log also

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with Threads. You can get info here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads

But, to point the problem with the code.

Android has a "UI" thread, responsible for rendering everything the user sees / touches. UI thread can't run long / heavy operations, since it may cause the UI seems laggy.

Fragment's "OnCreate" Method run on UI Thread. Any code inside it will also be on UI Thread.

Database operations are heavy. Android does not allow you to access / run database on UI Thread. What you need is to run:

```
 DBHelper myDBHelper = new DBHelper(intent.getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase mydb = myDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = mydb.rawQuery("select title, rating, strftime('%Y-%m-%d', visited) from myRestaurant", null);
```

and

```
db.close()
```

On a background thread. This comes to async programming. Since you'll need this in every app that has a database or connect to internet (requests are Heavy!), it's worth read about it.

Since you use Java, you can start here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/package-summary